# Refactor the code to reduce Assignment Branch Condition size

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am developing a Rails web application. But when I run rubocop to check the code. It said that the ABC (Assignment Branch Condition) size of the method below is too high. While I'm a newbie in Ruby on Rails, can someone give me some advice to refactor this block of code? For more details, I am implementing the third party authentication which allows user to sign in by facebook or google, etc.

Thank you

```
  def self.from_omniauth auth, current_user
    identity = Identity.find_by(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.id)
                       .first_or_initialize
    if identity.user.blank?
      user = current_user || User.find_by("email = ?",
                                          auth["info"]["email"])
      if user.blank?
        user = User.new
        user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0, 10]
        user.name = auth.info.name
        user.email = auth.info.email
        user.picture = auth.info.image
        return user.save(validate: false) if auth.provider == "twitter"

        user.save
      end
      identity.user_id = user.id
      identity.save
    end
    identity.user
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  def self.from_omniauth auth, current_user
    identity = Identity.find_by(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.id)
                       .first_or_initialize
    if identity.user.blank?
      user = current_user || User.find_by("email = ?",
                                          auth["info"]["email"])
      create_user(auth) if user.blank?

      identity.user_id = user.id
      identity.save
    end
    identity.user
  end

  def self.create_user(auth)
    user = User.new
    user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0, 10]
    user.name = auth.info.name
    user.email = auth.info.email
    user.picture = auth.info.image
    return user.save(validate: false) if auth.provider == "twitter"

    user.save
  end
```

Is something you can try. But if the complexity is actually needed you can set a comment to ignore that cop `# rubocop:disable ABC (Assignment Branch Condition)`, or whatever the actual name of the cop is. Also you can configure the ABC size if you feel the size set is too low

Comment: This works perfectly, a smalll correction is create_user method need self. to be called in from_omniauth. Thanks anw, I already fixed that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get any error like you are saying, so probably you should try # rubocop:disable ABC

when I saved this it added bracket in parameters

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth, current_user)
  identity = Identity.find_by(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.id)
                     .first_or_initialize
  if identity.user.blank?
    user = current_user || User.find_by("email = ?",
                                        auth["info"]["email"])
    if user.blank?
      user = User.new
      user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0, 10]
      user.name = auth.info.name
      user.email = auth.info.email
      user.picture = auth.info.image
      return user.save(validate: false) if auth.provider == "twitter"

      user.save
    end
    identity.user_id = user.id
    identity.save
  end
  identity.user
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I already refactored the code as the comment above.